# Which server to user for a rails 4 app which has long running requests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multithreading, concurrency, passenger, thin

I have a rails 4 application which has some methods which do perform a long taking call to an external API. The problem is that these requests block the entire app. And only one 1 user(request) can be served at the same time. That's not wanted.
So my idea was just using thin as web server since it is meant to be multithreaded and support concurrency. Am I right, that phusion in it's opensource version would not be able to run multiple requests at the same time

What is the best performing setup for a such a scenario?

Comment: You can tune Passenger open source to handle multiple concurrent connections so long as you spend most of the request waiting, that's basically what SSE is. You can read more about it here: https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/config/apache/tuning_sse_and_websockets/

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly suggest you look into one of the background job processing systems out there (my personal favorite is Sidekiq).  Offload these long running jobs to Sidekiq and reconfigure your application to accommodate (like checking back to see if the job is done, etc).

Comment: That's what I did. I used sidekiq but this means that I have to poll or stream results after the call to the api has been made. But what's the benefit over having having thin as server which allows many concurrent connections ?

Comment: Maybe nothing.  Really depends on your app and what "long taking" means.  At some point clients start to timeout, etc.

Comment: The requests take usually around 5 up to 30 seconds maximum, so timeout should not be a problem. IMHO, polling or streaming might be over-architectured in this case since polling will ping your app all the time and causes even more requests.So why not just having a long running requests which waits for the api call to finish.